# what does "A uses B, which is being defined" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

now i did do as the rules asked and first looked to see if this was answered already, and while i did find a post, it failed to solve my specific problem, thus i ask in my own.

for a brief bit of context, this error is within the node class for a double-linked-list class i am making, thus obviously the node has to have some kind of knowledge of its proceeding and preceding neighbors

the following code...

```
    template<class T> class dslListNode
    {
    public:
        dslListNode(T data, dslListNode<T>* next, dslListNode<T>* prev)
        : m_data(data)
        {
            this->m_next = next;
            this->m_prev = prev;
        }

        T m_data;
        dslListNode<T>* m_next, m_prev;   //<-- line twelve
        void purge()
        {
            if (this->m_next != NULL)
            {
                this->m_next->purge();
                delete this->m_next;
            }
        }
    private:
    };
```

...on line twelve wont stop giving me the following error

```
Error   C2460
'dslListNode<T>::m_prev': uses 'dslListNode<T>', which is being defined
```

so ya...

i am honestly at a loss as to what is going on right now, my skills at c++ aren't to the level at which i understand why such a thing is happening, with the internet up till now not helping in this respect, thus i ask for help.

why is this happening and what can i do to solve it?

apologies for my grammar and spelling btw =D

thanks in advanced =)

Comment: You can't have a class contain a member of the same type as itself  ... that would be an infinite descent

Comment: i think i get what your saying, but what do i do as a alternative then?

Comment: see the answers posted for a solution

Comment: General solution is: don't type any commas unless you know what you are doing. [Ouch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). [Ouch](http://www.mindtribe.com/2011/07/forgotten-c-the-comma-operator/).

Comment: i understand now, apoligies for me being stupid, another error popped up that confused me despite being totally unrelated, thanks for all the help lads =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next, m_prev;
```

is equivalent to:

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next;  // A pointer
dslListNode<T> m_prev;   // An object.
```

It's OK to have a pointer to `dslListNode<T>` in the definition of the class. A pointer to an incomplete type is allowed by the language.

However, you cannot have a member variable of type `dslListNode<T>` while defining the class itself. It's analogous to:

```
struct A
{
   A a;
};
```

It is not going to work because the definition of `A` requires the definition of `A`. This leads to infinite descent.

You need

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next;  // A pointer
dslListNode<T>* m_prev;  // Another pointer.
```

You can get that using a one liner:

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next, *m_prev;
```

However, the two line version is more readable. I strongly recommend using it.

Comment: To improve this answer, you should probably explain, what *incomplete type* means, and why the code in the question requires a *complete type* instead. Don't just hand out the fish.

Comment: @IInspectable, fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

In this case it means you left the `*` off of the declaration for `m_prev`.  That member will be an instance of `dslListNode` instead of a pointer to one.

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next, *m_prev;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a member variable of same class while defining the class, but you can create a pointer to the same class.
As said so in your code,

```
 dslListNode<T>* m_next, m_prev;
```

this means m_next is a pointer variable of dslListNode and m_prev is only variable. If you prefer to declare m_prev as a pointer variable you have to use pointer syntax appropriately as follows:

```
dslListNode<T>* m_next, *m_prev;
```